# Design page suddenly not loading on Visual Studio 2021. "Value does not fall within expected range"

Tags: compiler-errors

Completed my design on Visual Studio (windows form) and began coding for all the radio buttons etc. No code errors show up on that page. When I toggle back from cs tab to design tab nothing loads and I get an error message "Value does not fall within expected range".

Pics:

[error message on design page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nUVA.jpg)
[coding tab with no identified errors showing at bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxPGX.jpg)[designer.cs page showing no coding errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZEgT.jpg)

I am still new to all of this, and the information on the VS website doesn't really help me understand what happened, why, and more importantly how to fix it.

Any advice on how to fix would be helpful. As a side note I am doing this as a side project for my job (I'm a therapist for abused teens and not a programmer) and have been teaching myself as I go with the help of this forum and youtube. Meaning I have very little clue of what I'm actually doing other than "did this work?/did this not work" and will likely need a very simplified and dumbed down response.

Thank you in advance